# How to create log file with python logging only when error occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-handling

```
    logger = logging.getLogger("sample")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f"log_debug_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}", delay=False)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.debug(f"Start url: {url}")
    try:
        # executing block of code here..
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}", exc_info=True)
```

I want to create a log file only when error occurs. How can I achieve that?

Comment: When I am exectuing block of code I am also creating logs. So when my script fails I want to get log file to see at which stage of my script error occured

Comment: You seem to understand the concept of catching exceptions. If you want to create the log file only when an error occurs, what is stoping you from moving all the relevant code to the `except` block?

Comment: I can't move code relevant to logging to the except block because I am creating logs also inside try: block

Comment: In this case what does _I want to create a log file only when error occurs._ mean?

Comment: I want to have logs stored in a file when there is an error so I can see exactly at which point of executing try block (there are logs created each step of code) error occured

Comment: well, your current code would do that. It will write to log file in the `except` block

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to create a file when there is no error

Comment: But in the comment above you said that _I can't move code relevant to logging to the except block because I am creating logs also inside try: block_, so you need to create file even without error

Comment: Of course you can play with different level/handler combinations, e.g. file handler for ERROR or higher and in this case use `logger.error()` inside the exception block

Comment: Also note you have `logger.debug(f"Start url: {url}")` before the `try` so you need the file already here

Answer (score 0):

The [`logging.handlers.MemoryHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=memoryhandler#memoryhandler) is intended for this use case - you can specify a threshold level which flushes buffered log events to a separate handler (the *target*) for output. If that handler is a `FileHandler`, you can specify `delay=True` for it, which means it won't actually open/create the file until something needs to be written to it.